# Google Place Autocomplete append to div

Tags: google-maps, google-places-api

I have a google autocomplete on a modal and is working (Like [this example](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete?hl=pt-br)) but I have an issue. The modal jquery plugin that I'm using set overflow hidden to "html" when opened and if modal height is greater then document height the scroll that appears is from overlay (or backdrop whatever you call it). When autocomplete appears I think they are appended to html, so when I scroll modal the autocomplete stay fixed, looks like they are being appended to html.
The same happens with Jquery UI Autocomplete, but they have an option called "appendTo", and I just point it to a div inside modal and works perfectly.
I would to know if Google Place Autocomplete have an option like that.

[image]

When I scroll

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I just faced this issue. I working around the problem. I will hide the scrollbars when the focus is in the input field and show the scroll bars when the focus is lost from the input field. So the user cannot scroll around when they are choosing